# How do I connect my backbone model to the view?

Tags: view, model, backbone.js

This is my first time with backbone and I am trying to figure out why console.logging `this.model` *inside of my view* doesn't spit out my model which has some default attributes.

Instead, I get:

`function (){return a.apply(this,arguments)}`

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/amit_e/muLjV/33/

(Please open your console to see the results)

What am I doing wrong? How do I get access to my model inside my view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As View doesn't  define a single model with `model:Photo`. Ideally, `Model:Photo` has to be defined in a collection. 
 You should create an instance of Photo inside View seperately. So, it will work.

When I added  `var myPhoto = new Photo();` in initialize block of view. I found this working then.

**About usage of Collection:**

Collection is a group of Models. So, You should define it anywhere in View ( Initialize or render or cutom function). More specifically, Collection
is used in MVC architecture to perform operation on models collectively. For example, In your case Album could be a collection of Photos. 
You can store multiple instances on photo in Album. Album will be useful to you in operations like search, sort, add, delete of photos.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. How do I pass the collection to the view then?

Comment: Thanks Umesh. That does make things clear conceptually. But how would I go about outputting a collection through a view?